# Load images from oracle Table to User Form's Image Controls

Tags: excel, vba

1. I have a oracle table "Employee Details"  with Empno,Ename,Image.
2. I have 50 records in the table.
3. Using vba code I am able to down load the Images to my local file system.
4. I am not able to Dynamically add Image controls on the Userform and populate the images from the record set.

---

```
With Cn
        .Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & cboDsn.Value & ";" & "User ID=" & txtuser.Value & ";" & "Password=" & txtpwd.Value & ";"
        .Open
End With


        Rs.Open "select * from " & txtTname.Value & " order by empno", Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic



'Save the files  from DB to local file system
For R = 1 To Rs.RecordCount

        'Temporary file location for saving the image
        TempFileName = v_ApplPath & "\logs\" & Rs.Fields(3).Value

        With Strm
                .Type = adTypeBinary
                .Open
                .Write Rs.Fields(4).Value
                .SaveToFile TempFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
                .Close
        End With

    Rs.MoveNext

Next R
```

I would like to have a scrollbar to see all the 50 records with images.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to add Image controls Dynamically to a Frame Object basing on the number of records returned by the record set.

For R = 1 To Rs.RecordCount

```
    TempFileName = v_ApplPath & "\logs\" & Rs.Fields(3).Value

    With Strm
            .Type = adTypeBinary
            .Open
            .Write Rs.Fields(4).Value
            .SaveToFile TempFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite

                    Set NewImage = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", "Image" & R)
                    With NewImage
                        .Top = ImageTopPos
                        .Left = ImageLeftPos + 250
                        .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
                        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
                        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
                        .BackColor = &HFFC0C0
                        .BorderColor = &HFFC0C0
                        .Width = 50
                        .Height = 50
                        .Picture = LoadPicture(TempFileName, 50, 50)
                    End With

                    ImageTopPos = NewImage.Top + NewImage.Height + 10

                    With Frame1
                            .Visible = True
                            .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
                                    V_ScrollBarHeight = ImageTopPos
                            .ScrollHeight = V_ScrollBarHeight + 25
                    End With

            .Close
    End With
                    Fsys.DeleteFile (TempFileName)

                    frmImageLoad.Repaint
Rs.MoveNext
```

Next R